# Преобразование ресурса-массива в динамический массив ArrayList

Tags: java, android, массивы, arraylist

Как преобразовать массив-ресурс в динамический массив `ArrayList`?

```
<string-array name="name">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/157950/3212712) на en-SO, находящемуся на первой строке выдачи гугла по запросу

> [array to arraylist java](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=array%20to%20arraylist%20java)

для сих целей существует статический метод `asList` класса `Arrays`, принимающий массив чего-либо в качестве аргумента. Результат вызова этого метода надо передать в конструктор `ArrayList`. Т.е. в вашем случае удет как-то так:

```
String[] arrayFromRes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
ArrayList<String> arrayListFromStringArrayFromResources = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayFromRes));
```